# Launch RancherOs with Openstack and Terraform

Tags: openstack, terraform, rancher

Hi running the latest OpenStack, Terraform and RancherOs.

From the Openstack UI I can get rancher to work and I can pass in my own ssh keys for instance but you need to explicitly click the configuration drive otherwise it will not accept the user data.

I don't think this is possible with terraform is it?

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "terraform-rancher" {
  name            = "terraform-rancher"
  image_name      = "RancherOs"
  flavor_name     = "t2.xlarge"
  security_groups = ["default"]

  #This is on the same path as my terraform file.
  user_data       = "${file("test.txt")}"


  network {
    name = "provider"
  }
}
```

The instance launches and gets created but when I look at the logs Rancher cannot seem to find the config with:

```
cloud-init: Datasource unavailable, skipping: cloud-drive: /media/config-2 (lastError: no such file or directory)
```

From Openstack UI it works fine, but as stated you have to click the config drive check box.

```
cloud-init: Datasource available: cloud-drive: /media/config-2
```

Answer (score 2):

To get it work like in the UI, the `config_drive` parameter in the instance configuration needs to be set to `true`.